# How do I concatenate combinations of letters and numbers in APL?

Tags: string, concatenation, number-formatting, apl, dyalog

I'm in Dyalog 17 and would like to generate unique names to be used with its graphics object library.  So, for example, I have the letter `'l'` and want to take the number `1`, convert it to a character and then concatenate the two together to form `'l1'`.  This is such trivial stuff in other languages but I can't find the documentation explaining how to do this in APL.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate the letter `'l'` to the number `1` to form the characters `'l1'` you do this:

```
'l',⍕1
```

Comment: That is indeed correct, and good for single instance, but you can also use the system function FMT which is very powerful for formatting and decorating numbers as text. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The system function ⎕FMT can be of use here. For example:

```
       'P<I>ZI7' ⎕FMT ⍳10 
I000000
I000001
I000002
I000003
I000004
I000005
I000006
I000007
I000008
I000009
```

The format string specifies to format the numbers as integers, in width of 7, zero filling, with a positive left decoration of the letter'I'.

Comment: It should be noted that `⎕FMT` *always* returns a matrix, which means that simple things like `'abc',⎕FMT 123` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on APL2 in the Mainframe, so my answer might not be exactly what you're after, but here's how I would do it:

```
∊⍕¨'L',1
```

So first catanate the letter and the numeric digits. Then FORMAT EACH to produce a vector of character scalars. Finally, ENLIST to produce a simple vector.

This is a slight generalization of SteveH's reply. More general in the sense that it handles input strings (rather than scalars) and works equally well regardless if the digit or letter comes first.

Comment: To print out the factorial of `5`, I used: `∊⍕¨"",!5`